# code block does not work when immediately following a list

Tags: support, markdown

- here is a list
- followed by a code block
- or that´s how it was intended

  sample input      sample output
  108,174,106       [0.3793103448275862, 0.0, 0.3908045977011494, 0.3176470588235294]
  0,0,0             0,0,0,1
  170,255,238       33,0,7,0
  0x0088ff          1,0.4667,0,0
  [250,235,215]     [0,6,14,1.96]

  ## 123456           .7907,.3953,0,.6627
- apparently I have to use backticks and line breaks instead

  `sample input      sample output`
  `108,174,106       [0.3793103448275862, 0.0, 0.3908045977011494, 0.3176470588235294]`
  `0,0,0             0,0,0,1`
  `170,255,238       33,0,7,0`
  `0x0088ff          1,0.4667,0,0`
  `[250,235,215]     [0,6,14,1.96]`
  `#123456           .7907,.3953,0,.6627`

or insert a somehow matching paragraph

```
sample input      sample output
108,174,106       [0.3793103448275862, 0.0, 0.3908045977011494, 0.3176470588235294]
0,0,0             0,0,0,1
170,255,238       33,0,7,0  
0x0088ff          1,0.4667,0,0
[250,235,215]     [0,6,14,1.96]  
#123456           .7907,.3953,0,.6627
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use 8 spaces of indentation if you want the code block as part of the list:

  ```
  Like this
  Neat, huh?
  ```
- Otherwise, if you want a code block immediately *after* a list, put an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) with no indentation between the list and code block to reset the SE parser to normal paragraph mode.

```
Check out the markdown of this answer in the
revision history to see what it looks like.
```

Comment: invisble paragraph. bright idea. I have no clue where to look for the revision history; but the explanation is sufficient.

Comment: @Titus Click on "edited X hours ago" (and then you can look at the markdown there)

Comment: I accidentally found an even shorter solution today: `<!>` does the same trick as `<!-- -->`